How to approach profs from different unis for (mini) research projects?
I am set to complete my Masters this year (in 2-3 months) from a local university in India, and I haven't done a research project yet throughout my UG or PG years. I really like Algebra and Topology and related fields, but never thought of the prospects of doing a research project. To top that, our semester exams take place exactly when other institutes in India conduct their summer research projects, so I never could apply for a summer research internship either.
Now, I get to know that to apply abroad, I have to have some decent projects to my name. It's not that I didn't think about a PhD earlier, but I never cared enough to think seriously about it, and thus plan my moves accordingly. In short, maybe I did screw up a little. Anyways, so now, with my Masters ending, I have to take things seriously and get my hands onto some projects.
I will be applying to the summer research programs here in India, but most of them accept only up to first year Masters' students. So most of the doors are closed. I am thinking of applying to colleges abroad for online research internship, not necessarily the summer research programs. I have heard from a friend from a different field that he had secured an internship through individually cold mailing profs.
How do I write to profs from different universities, India and abroad, for a research internship, online or offline(preferably online, since money is a huge factor if it is unpaid and offline), and what might the format be for a nice email to mail a prof, that might increase my chances of securing a project?

What do you exactly want the professor to do?

@MaartenBuis To assign me a project

Cold emailing will have a very low chance of success, but you never know. Using contacts of professors at your current institution likely has a somewhat higher chance. But consider why a professor would want to set up a remote project with someone they have never met.

@JonCuster I am looking for advice in general, regarding what to do

What does "assign a project" mean? I can assign you a project right now by saying "do some research" , but I guess that that is not what you mean. When you ask something from someone you need to be very precise what it is exactly you want from that person.

@MaartenBuis a guided project, preferably publishable in a journal of considerable repute.

I'm moderately shaky on the official policy, but my understanding is that expletives are generally not allowed without some compelling reason to allow them https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79974/whats-the-so-policy-for-swearing, so I edited the one out for a euphemism.

If you are asking for "a guided project", you are asking to receive educational services for free. Universities typically reserve those services for the students enrolled in at that university. So you are asking professors to volunteer their spare time. This means you are competing for time with their significant other, their children, parents, and friends. So I think @Buffy is correct in his answer, that you are extremely unlikely to be successful.

You are also asking for the project to be "publishable in a journal of considerable repute". This differs a bit from discipline to discipline, but in my discipline there are no more MA level projects left that are publishable, let alone publishable in a journal of considerable repute. But there are discipline where all the low hanging fruit has not been grazed away a hundred years ago. Still even in those disciplines that is a big ask. There is a reason why most people need at least an additional 4 years of specialized training (PhD) in order to publish such articles.

In short, I would encourage you to start working on a plan B: what will you do in the very likely case where you will not get such guided project. Again Buffy made some suggestions.

If all you want is to be assigned a project, then I'd suggest that you just ask one of your local professors to make a suggestion.
However, if you want guidance and a final evaluation, the problem is much harder, possibly unsolvable in most cases. I think the people that are successful in cold mailing for such things are rare and lucky.
There is little incentive for a (busy) professor to provide any guidance. They are unlikely to be paid for it, even by yourself.
And a local professor is much more likely to have a way to provide a bit of support, assuming you can meet with them occasionally.
One option is to ask one of your professors to suggest a recent paper or two for you to read. It could be one of theirs or not. Read it and enough of the supporting bibliography so that you get an understanding of a narrow field of study. This would be an essential skill in most doctoral programs. You might not get "credit" for it but you might learn something.
